# Multi level indexed dataframe: count the level values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a multi indexed dataframe of two index, STNAME (state name) and CTYNAME (county name)
[image: Two level indexed dataframe]

The dataframe represents county details at each state. Therefore, there are some States (STNAME) and each State has some counties (CTYNAME).

I need to find the State with maximum number of counties in it and sort the States on the basis of the number of counties each has.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STNAME':['AL'] * 3 + ['MI'] * 4 + ['NY'] , 
                   'CTYNAME':list('abcdefgh'),
                   'COL': range(8) }).set_index(['STNAME','CTYNAME'])
print (df)
                COL
STNAME CTYNAME     
AL     a          0
       b          1
       c          2
MI     d          3
       e          4
       f          5
       g          6
NY     h          7
```

First get values of first level by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.value_counts.html), which by default sorts by counts:

```
a = df.index.get_level_values('STNAME').value_counts()
print (a)
MI    4
AL    3
NY    1
Name: STNAME, dtype: int64

#get first value of index
print (a.index[0])
MI
```

And for change ordering use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.reindex(a.index, level=0)
print (df)
                COL
STNAME CTYNAME     
MI     d          3
       e          4
       f          5
       g          6
AL     a          0
       b          1
       c          2
NY     h          7
```